# Unit Test GraphQL schemas/queries made in AWS AppSync?

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync

I have a simple question: is there a way/program/method to create unit tests to test the API Url generated on AWS AppSync to verify the validity of created GraphQL schemas, queries, mutations, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open-source AppSync Serverless plugin which has offline emulator support. You may find it useful: https://github.com/sid88in/serverless-appsync-plugin#offline-support

Another good recommendation is to have two separate AppSync APIs. One API is hosting you production traffic. The other is to test changes before they go to production. This is significantly easier if you use **Cloudformation** (highly recommended) to manage your infrastructure.

If you want to validate your API is working periodically (every minute or so), you could create a canary like the following:

1. Create a Lambda function which runs on a schedule. This lambda function will make various GraphQL requests. It can emit success/failure metrics to CloudWatch.
2. Setup a CloudWatch alarm so you can be notified if your success/failure metric is out of the ordinary.

For the canary use-case see:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html

Comment: This is perfect! Excellent idea having two APIs and a scheduled Lambda function! Thank you!

Comment: I would rather have something like requests in python that can be used to run queries and mutations against the AppSync graphql.  This would be much more convenient for testing outside of needing in additional AWS plumbing.  Is there anything for that?

Answer (score 0):

There is also amplify [amplify-appsync-simulator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amplify-appsync-simulator) package that is supposed to help with testing appsync, but there is no documentation on how you should use it. It is used by [serverless-appsync-simulator](https://github.com/bboure/serverless-appsync-simulator) Michael wrote and Amplify itself.