# How to write unit test cases for AWS Appsync

Tags: amazon-web-services, unit-testing, aws-appsync, testcase

I've been using AWS appsync service. However, I'm not able to figure out a way to write unit test cases for the development I've been doing.

Please see if anyone can share any information in this regard.

Comment: It depends what you need. If you writing an app with JS you can use jest. If you search github you can find some repos with some examples tests like this here https://github.com/esoh/fitzpo/blob/develop/fitzpo-core/__tests__/index.js

Comment: thank you so much @KevinRegenrek  However, I've couple of queries. Let me share the tech stack I've been using: serverless frameowrk from serverless.com ,  nodejs, aws appsync, serverless-appsync-plugin . I can share further information if required. Now coming to queries. 1. still a little unclear how to write test cases using my laptop without logging into AWS console 2. how to execute these test cases locally and over AWS appsync console..

Comment: Also, just to clarify the requirement, the question is on how to write automated unit test cases for backend i.e. appsync APIs ( not for appsync client at the front side)

Comment: I think you are looking for this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54046045/unit-test-graphql-schemas-queries-made-in-aws-appsync

Comment: did you found any documentation regarding this?